# Copy/cut and paste sometimes doesn't work on Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 14.04

Copy/cut and paste sometimes doesn't work on Nautilus, the bug seems to be random and the only way to fix it is closing and opening Nautilus again.

Update:

I just noted that when this happen all keyboard shortcuts stop working, trying to copy and paste using the mouse doesn't work either.

Ubuntu: 14.04 | Nautilus: 3.10.1

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Fixes are released as updates in Ubuntu. If you want to report this issue to the developers, you should do so on Launchpad.net. Software development is beyond the scope for this site. It's more of a Q and A site.

Comment: @Dennis, did you report the issue? I didn't find it on a quick search and would like to avoid duplicating it...

Comment: any update? Someone have Bug report link?

Comment: lets try a workaround, may be something that is version independent could be the solution, check at http://askubuntu.com/questions/474715/nautilus-copy-paste-suddenly-stop-working-how-to-workaround-qdbus

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/489574/271328

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Known bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1322925 Please click "this bug affects me" there to convince devs of its urgency.